# '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization during nodmon

Tags: webpack

I am getting this error:

(node:8319) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization

please help me its been a week nothing is found on google how to resolve it?
node - v14.16.0